# What is "write" syntax in AMZI Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I wonder if there is something like "write" (if in Turbo Prolog) or "printf" (if in C) syntax but in AMZI Prolog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using the `write/1` predicate?

```
write('Hello world'), nl.
```

???

Comment: i mean something to write something in each of your (for e.g.) recursion.

Comment: If you actually try to write down a half-working example it will be more clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately, I just wondering, not in the middle of a task require such.